# Cancel submit on a rails remote form_for

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have a `form_for(:remote=>true)` working but I want to display a regular javascript confirmation box before submitting.

Is there anyway to achieve this? 
Ideally some kind of :before or :onsubmit that would accept cancelling submission with something like: `return confirm("Are you sure?");` or maybe a javascript event hook?

Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this easily with [the `confirm` option](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-submit_tag):

```
<%= for_form @my_thing, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :my_value %>
  <%= f.submit 'Submit', confirm: 'Are you sure?' %>
<% end %>
```

You need to be using a [Rails UJS driver](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) (enabled by default on new Rails projects) for this to work seamlessly.

There are also [hooks into the form submission lifecycle you can access](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/) if you so wish:

- `ajax:beforeSend` - triggered before the XHR request is made; return false to cancel the request
- `ajax:success` - triggered on a successful response from the server
- `ajax:error` - triggered on an error response from the server
- `ajax:complete` - triggered on either a success or error response from the server

So, as an example, you should be able to mimic the `confirm` form helper option with some code like this:

```
$("#my_remote_form").on('ajax:beforeSend', function() {
  return confirm("Are you sure?");
});
```